# Is it possible to create a user in Thinktecture IdentityServer that can only be authenticated by a certificate

Tags: federated-identity, thinktecture-ident-server

Is it possible to create a User in Thinktecture IdentityServer that can only be authenticated by a certificate?  The default IdentityServer UI seems to indicate that a User needs a Username/Password credential which you then associate with a certificate - but I'd like to have one for which the password is irrelevant and can only be authenticated by the certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - the way it works right now is that the cert thumbprint is basically a pointer to an existing account. You can of course create a very long random password for that account.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response - I'm having some trouble applying this in a WsTrustChannel scenario to obtain a token though as I've detailed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138715/how-to-specify-a-certificate-as-the-credentials-for-a-wstrustchannel-with-thinkt